# Check for PDF/X,VT,UA,E Standards programmatically

Tags: c#, pdf, iso

(this is my first time asking a question so it might not be perfect)

Hello,

I need to make a program that detects what format a pdf file is using according to the `ISO standards(A,X,UA,VT,E)`.

Is there any sort of data in the pdf file that tells this?

I have already tried the ***itextsharp*** libary but this only covers PDF/a as far as I know.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: The Problem with PDF is: It can state inside the PDF that it complies to some Standard, but that means *nothing*. You'd still have to check if that is indeed the case. There are some libraries on the market that can check that (mostly non-free).

Comment: @Fildor Do you know any of these libaries? I tried looking them up but I can't find any.

Comment: Adobe PreFlight for example just to name the "inventors" solution.